# Is there a difference between these Session variable declarations?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using ASP.NET 4.5 MVC3 and C#

Is there a difference between:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["OrderId"]
```

And:

```
Session["OrderId"]
```

OR are both part of the "System.Web.HttpContext.Current" namespace?

Thanks.

Comment: if you have `Using System.Web.HttpContext.Current` at the top of your file, then they are the same

Comment: ... and if I do not? Thanks for the reply...

Comment: You would have to hover over `Session` in Visual Studio in order to see its namespace. It may very well be `System.Web.HttpContext`, or if there is a class called `Session` in some other namespace, it may be that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.Web` is namespace.

`HttpContext` is name of class.

`HttpContext.Current` holds instance of this class for current request.

`Session` in controller is just faster way to reach this object, so this is generally the same.